# Connect does not call mapStateToProps under certain conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

- I am learning React, Redux and firebase; and creating a small word game.
- There are three reducers (A, B and C).
- The problem is that in the component shown below (simplified, but tested) mapStateToProps is only called when the states of B or C change; never with A.
- There are several components and this component is the only one that experiences this problem. All the other components receive mapStateToProps call as expected.
- I tested it by making an update to B/C whenever A is updated.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Keyboard from './Keyboard';

const intiState = {
    key: 0,
}

class PlayGame extends Component {
    state=intiState;
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.newGame();
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div key={this.state.key}>
                <div className="">
                    <Keyboard />
                </div >
            </div>
        )
    }
}
let mapDispatchToProps = {
    newGame: () =>{return {type: 'NEW_GAME'}},
}
let mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
    console.log("MapStateToProps ",state);
    return{completeState: state};
}
 
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PlayGame)
```

Comment: These other components you mention are using state from reducer A? And you verified that reducer A is properly hooked up to your store like B and C?

Comment: Yes and I hope so, they're connected in same way.

Comment: It is interesting that when I update state of reducer A, it is reflected in other components, just not the component I posted above.

Comment: Show your reducer code.

Comment: could you paste the snippet of `action` and `reducer`?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/dMm8hBsk

Comment: All of your supporting functions mutate state instead of returning new state. [Don't mutate state](https://redux.js.org/troubleshooting#never-mutate-reducer-arguments). `NEW_KEYPRESS` is probably the action that's causing your problems, specifically, right?

Comment: I just created a TEST_ACTION that adds 1 to "state.k". It does call mapStateToProps other components, but not in this one. So, NEW_KEYPRESS is not the only action that's not working.

Comment: @PratyakshAgarwal Where is the code you are currently using and are you still mutating state?

Comment: @HMR I tried to correct Mutating state by changing GameReducer() to https://pastebin.com/X7JvVYqj while the rest is same as in the above file. Idk if state mutation is fixed but this still does not work. I have temporarily worked around this issue by creating a function that dispatches the action to GameReducer and then dispatches a dummy action to another reducer. As stated before, this makes the reducer work just fine but I know its not a solution so I will keep looking and learning.

Comment: I also read up on the link provided by Adam, proceeded to change newKeyPresses() into non-mutating function. Didn't work. Again, the workaround still holds.